# Increment look back value within a configuration file daily +1

Tags: shell-script

I have a configuration file that needs to be incremented daily.

E.g.

```
report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=60
```

This file contains multiple entries such as the one above that contains different values.  I need to open the property file search for this specific entry, and increment the value by +1 each day for a total of 30 days.

E.g.

```
report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=61

report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=62

report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=63
```

I am new to scripting, and I'm not sure what method would accomplish this task.

Should I use awk, sed, implement a counter, or a combination of methods?

Comment: _New to scripting_ should not be an excuse to not try anything by yourself.  That said, if you try searching a bit then you'd find numerous examples of manipulating `value` in `VAR=value` form.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to edit a file that looks like what you posted, use something like

```
perl -i  -pe 's/report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=\K\d+/$&+1/e' file
```

#### Explanation

The `-i` enables in-place editing, so the changes are saved to the original file, `-p` means "print each line after executing whatever script is givven by -e"/

The `s///` is the substitution operator, it works like `s/source/replacement`.

The regular expression used is looking for the string `report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=` followed by one or more numbers (`\d+`). The `\K` discards whatever was matched before, allowing `$&`, whicih is a special variable holding whatever was just matched, to point to the numbers alone.

Finally, we replace it with `$&+1`, the value matched plus one. This (evaluating something within the `s///` operator) is activated by the `s///e` flag at the end of the `s///e`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to edit the file in place each day, which you probably don't want to do, you could do something like this:

```
$ echo 'report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=61' \
    | awk -F= '
        /report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data/{
            printf("%s=%d\n", $1, $2+1)
        }
    '
report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data=62
```

But that would require saving to a temp file then replacing the original each time. As `devnull` mentioned, it would be better to replace the values with `$vars` and invoke the script with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do with `awk`, however the standard approach is to output to a temporary file and then replace the original, using Linux `mktemp` you can do:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp --tmpdir=.)
awk -F= '{
  if($1=="report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data")
    print $1"="$2+1
  else
    print
  }' in_file >"$tempfile"
mv "$tempfile" in_file
```

Some versions of `awk` have the `-i` (inplace) option, meaning you can just do:

```
awk -iF= '{
  if($1=="report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data")
    print $1"="$2+1
  else
    print
  }' in_file
```

Or if the `sponge` utility (part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)) is available:

```
awk -F= '{
  if($1=="report.lookback.days.to.retrieve.data")
    print $1"="$2+1
  else
    print
  }' in_file |
sponge in_file
```

Of course if the input file doesn't contain any other lines apart from the one you want to increment (or if it does and you just want to delete them), then the `awk` part can be simplifed.

Comment: The tempfile awk solution worked!  I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @user65231, the `sponge` solution is probably the best, `sponge` should be in the `moreutils` package. If this answer (or any other) is the one you are looking for, please take a moment to click the check mark and choose it as the solution.